# C# Winforms Usercontrol drag and snap to panel (runtime)

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, custom-controls

I am trying to write a program to manage tasks from my team. For this I use drag&drop capable custom `UserControls`. I try the following: When the `UserControl` is dragged over a `slot`, the control should then snapped into the `slot`.  The problem seems to be that the slot does not get the events like `"MouseEnter"` or `"DragEnter"`. Does anyone know a workaround, or is it possible to pass events down?
I think I just need a little push in the right direction.

**Edit:**

Main functionality:
The user control, let's call it `task`, should be docked into a `slot` when released over it.
A `slot` consists of properties and a panel. The task should appear in the panel.

Bonus:
A `task`, should dock into the different `slots` while dragging. So that it is always visible where the 'task' is placed when it is released.

I hope this shows what I am trying to do.

**Edit 2**
To clarification: I use the "MouseDown", "MouseUp" and "MouseMove" for the drag an drop.

Here you can see my Example the blueish panel is my task. The white the slot it should snap to. [image: Task next to the Slot]

On the second picture I drag the Task over the Slot panel. The mouse is not visable here but it's right beside the "K" of task.

[image: Task over the slot]

i have added for testing the following code. Which should color the panel inside the slot in a color if an event is raised. But the color stays white.

```
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }

    private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.BackColor = Color.Violet;
    }
```

Why I don't get events on the Slotpanel?
I hope that this helps to understand my problem.

Comment: What's the drop target? How do you define the slots?

Comment: A 'Slot' is an other userControl. The Droptarget is a Panel inside the 'Slot'. 
If possible I try to snap the Control to the 'Slot' before I let go of the control, so it displays where it snaps to while draging. But one step after another.

Comment: I don't have any idea how you are handling drag & drop, but no matter whether you are using standard drag & drop events or using mouse events, you need, in the DragEnter, or DragOver or MouseEnter or MouseMove events, highlight the target control which is under the cursor.

Comment: I'm using the mouse events for the drag and drop. 
My problem is that the "DragEnter" ,"DragOver" or "MouseEnter" on the slot/panel are not thrown. I have nit tried "MouseMove" i will try this tomorrow and give you feedback.

I think that the e.g. the "DragEnter" from the Slot is not called, because the "Task" panel, which I drag, is in front of it. Does that make any sence? I try to make a picture of it and post it as an update on the question later.

Comment: I was able to implement the base functionality in WPF (with my little WPF knowledge) . I would still be interested how that is possible in WinForms

Comment: It's a bit dependent to your UserControl structure. But the example using two panels would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: My user controls `Slot` and `Task` contain only one panel and one label. No complexity here. Unfortunately, I don't see this as straight forward like you do. Maybe you can help me there. As mentioned i'm not talking about droping, i mean hover over a slot while dragging a Task. While hovering the task should snap in the Slotpanel
I can drag my `Task` but the `Slot` doesn't know when a Task need to added as its child. There is no event fired on the panel of the slot. 
I was able to implement the functionality in WPF. It is now only a question of interest why my slot does not get any events.